# Is it possible to avoid Google Hangout Chat link preview's displaying authentication challenges?

Tags: google-chat

Hi we use Google Hangouts Chat at work. We like seeing link previews, but if we link to an internal resource protected by gsuite autherization, the link preview is just a box telling the bot to sign in. Is there a way of avoiding this?

[image]

Comment: So you are trying to share a file that can only be access by people in your organisation with a bot?

Comment: I am sharing a link that is protected by login. So I don't want the login challenge to be displayed. Most links are like this. It just clutters the interface. I want it to show nothing. Just leave the URL in text form and don't try to preview anything. It's a Google login challenge, so surely chat can figure out a way of detecting it and make a decision based on it.

Comment: I would just like a simple "Link Previews" on/off switch in settings.  I don't need to see any link previews.  Another annoying side effect of link previews is the screen jumps as the preview is fetch and makes continuity while scrolling impossible.

Comment: I assume this still hasn't been added?